# Twitter API response not always returning entities media as expected

Tags: php, twitter

Consider a call to retrieve a Twitter user's list of favorites using [abraham/twitteroauth PHP library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth):

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json
```

Given the following parameters:

```
$params = array(
    'screen_name' => $screenName,
    'count' => $count,
    'include_entities' => true,
);
```

Whereas all requested tweets actually show/embed a photo on the Twitter site, the related `media` fields expected to be found within the `entities` parent fields are not always present in the API response.

[Here's a tweet](https://twitter.com/BlindTasters/status/798164229060722688) whose response include the field, and [another one](https://twitter.com/DamienPiq/status/798642953057013760) whose response does NOT include it. You'll found respective `JSON` responses in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/davidloubere/8331a2b523772d99c669e1e720aa4afc

Does someone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Can you give your queries and Twitter API response for both examples?

Comment: Make sure you are passing `include_entities=true`

Comment: Question has been updated following above comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens because recently Twitter announced REST API changes that introduced two Tweets types:

- `Classic Tweet` - A Tweet object where the total length of the text
  content does not exceed 140 characters
- `Extended Tweet` - A Tweet object which includes hidden entities (e.g.    leading @mentions and trailing attachment) and where the
  text content    exceeds 140 characters in length.

They also introduced `Compatibility` mode which is default when you work with Twitter REST API. There is also `Extended` which you should set explicitly.

Citate from the documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets:

> "There will be two modes for rendering Tweet JSON objects to API
>   clients: compatibility mode and extended mode. Compatibility mode is
>   the default mode for the public REST and Streaming APIs and Gnip
>   products, and is designed to not break existing clients.
>   ... The existing text field will contain a truncated version of the
>   Tweet text, followed by an ellipsis character, a space, and a
>   shortened self-permalink URL.  ... The existing entity fields
>   (mentions, urls, media, etc.), will only contain entities that are
>   fully contained within the text value."

So, the first Tweet is `Classic`, and the second is `Extended` that gets truncated when you fetch it in `Compatibility mode`. You can get its full version by setting `tweet_mode=extended` in your Twitter REST API call.

Comment: OMG this works !. the standart search api doesn't document this but it still works !

Comment: I had this problem for several days. It works like a charm now